# Controlling for multiple variables in R

Tags: r, linear-regression

Running a regression to examine the effect of different variables (bedrooms, bathrooms, square foot living, square foot total, floors, age and condition) on the price. Is it possible to control for 2 variables? I know the code for one is

`f<- lm(price~sqft*bathrooms)`

Would it make sense to do either of the following

`f<- lm(price~sqft*bedroom+bathroom)` or `f<- lm(price~sqft*bedroom*bathroom)`

Thanks

Comment: The answer is "yes, possibly".

Comment: if you want to 'control' for bathroom then `f<- lm(price~sqft*bedroom+bathroom)` is the way to go. The answer from @Glen_b found here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25711041/r-linear-regression-control-for-a-variable might offer an insight.

Comment: Just to clarify - your syntax `f<- lm(price~sqft*bathrooms)` is testing an interaction between sqft and bathrooms which is not normally what I would consider "controlling for" - so it may be that what you actually want in the first instance is `f<- lm(price~sqft + bathrooms)` you can then add bathroom as per @Maylo's code